# How to move between different views in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have a Login view in my iPhone app. If the user successfully authenticates I want to move him from LoginViewController screen to MyViewController screen. Below is my code,

```
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){
        NSLog(@"Authentication correct");

        if(self.myviewController==nil)
        {
            MyViewController *myController=
            [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            self.myviewController=myController;
            [myController release];
        }
}
```

But somehow the app doesnt do anything when i click on the Login button even though the authentication is correct. As i am new to iphone app development can anybody please help me out with the code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To transition between views you're going to want to read up on `UINavigationControllers`.  A `UINavigationController` is an object that manages a hierarchy of views.  The `UINavigationController` is like a road map for going from one view to another in your applications flow and it achieves it's most basic features by calling the methods `pushViewController:animated` (to transition to a new view controller) and `popViewController:animated` (to transition back to the preview view).

In the case of your project you'd want to do the following.

- Allocate and initialize a `UINavigationController` (in your application delegate if you plan on the login screen to be where your program starts) and assign it's root view to your login view controller.
- If the user has been successfully authenticated, you would then construct an instance of the `UIViewController` you want to transition to and then instruct the `UINavigationController` to push this next view controller onto the navigation stack by calling `pushViewController:animated:`
- At this point lets say you want the user to log out and return to the login screen once again, you can call this method `popViewController:animated`.

[Here's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the class reference for `UINavigationController` to get you started.  It's got some great pictures explaining it's structure.

Comment: Happy to help, I hope you're enjoying iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UINavigationController` .